# running test on 2 different environment (DEV & STaging) simultaneously while both of these environment have 2 different urls

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have 2 environments where I need to run same set of test. both of these environment have different urls & other properties like credentials & DB names r different too. I have 1 appsettings files /environment .
is it possible to invoke test simultaneously on these  2 environments .

Currently I have setup my project to load the corresponding appsettings.json for the environment value set by **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT**

Comment: 2x different host environments? And you want to invoke some tests at the same time during runtime?

Comment: kind of yes. lets say there r two staging environments or two sets of staging environment "stg1" & "stg2" . these have 2 different urls : http://stg1.com ,http://stg2.com

Comment: What kind if system is it? Web, API, background service, other?

Comment: its Web. Its a Selenium specflow automation project on dotnet core 3.1